# How to connect to internet with nokia x2-01

Tags: internet, connection

I wanna connect my ubuntu pc to internet using my nokia x2-01

but i cant do it like other phones
it just detect the phone and display disconnected now you are offline
i tried gnome pp also
but invain
any solution?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/

Comment: I know about nokuntu ,it just wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using  [wvdial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wvdial)

1. Install wvdial from a Ubuntu Live CD
2. Execute this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo wvdialconf
   ```
3. Execute this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
   ```

   edit the file with your configuration.
4. Execute this command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo wvdial
   ```

Answer (score 0):

u have to connect through the blutooth easily first u have to do pairing phone devise in your pc and go to blutooth settings then click on the contiue and select network as a mobile and then click on the wifi icon then click enable network and then click the your devise network it automatically internet will be on your mobile like wise you should connect nokia mobile

Answer (score -1):

it depends on the type of network line you are using.
form your service provider request for internet browsing settings for phone configuration and then you are good to go.
To connect to internet by using phone through PC kindly download Nokia PC suit and instal in your system and connect your data cable USB cord to the system. Now launch Nokia PC Suit and click on connect and select your Phone mode and click ok to connect to internet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Are you talking about Nokia PC Suit for Windows? Generally Windows programs don't work in Ubuntu. Please edit your answer and clarify. A link to the suit will be useful too.